# sharepoint 3.0 : access is denied after install

Tags: sharepoint

I just finished install sharepoint 3.0 on a w2k3 enterprise server.  It says installation successfully completed.  Then when i attempt to go to 'Sharepoint Products and Technologies configuration wizard, i receive the following error:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in
>   your application.  If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore
>   this error and attempt to continue. 
>   If you Quit, the application will
>   close immediately.
>
> Access is denied.  (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> See the end of this message for
>   details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog
>   box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException
>   ex)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String
>   bstrUrl, String&
>   pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String&
>   pbstrTitle, String& pbstrDescription,
>   Guid& pguidID, String&
>   pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32&
>   pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32&
>   pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16&
>   pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16&
>   pnCollation, UInt32& pnCollationLCID,
>   Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16&
>   pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16&
>   pnAltCalendarType, Boolean&
>   pbShowWeeks, Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear,
>   UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16&
>   pnWorkDays, Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour,
>   Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour, Int16&
>   pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags,
>   Boolean& bConnectedToPortal, String&
>   pbstrPortalUrl, String&
>   pbstrPortalName, Int32&
>   plWebTemplateId, Int16&
>   pnProvisionConfig, String&
>   pbstrDefaultTheme, String&
>   pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String&
>   pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String&
>   pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String&
>   pbstrCustomJSUrl, String&
>   pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String&
>   pbstrMasterUrl, String&
>   pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String&
>   pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String&
>   pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object&
>   pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor,
>   UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean&
>   bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean&
>   bHasUniquePerm, Guid&
>   pguidUserInfoListID, Guid&
>   pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32&
>   plSiteFlags, DateTime&
>   pdtLastContentChange, DateTime&
>   pdtLastSecurityChange, String&
>   pbstrWelcomePage)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioning.TryGetIsSiteProvisioned(String
>   template, String relativePath,
>   Nullable`1 port, SPSite&
>   provisionedSite, SPWeb&
>   provisionedWeb, Uri& provisionedUri)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WelcomeForm.ShowNextFormForServerRoleSingleServer()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WelcomeForm.PsconfigBaseFormNextButtonClickedEventHandler(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3607 (GDR.050727-3600)
>       CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- psconfigUI
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6500.5000
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Common%20Files/Microsoft%20Shared/web%20server%20extensions/12/BIN/psconfigui.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3614 (GDR.050727-3600)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6535.5003
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SharePoint/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint.SetupConfiguration.Intl
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6413.1000
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SharePoint.SetupConfiguration.intl/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.SetupConfiguration.intl.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.ServiceProcess
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint.Security
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.4518.1016
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SharePoint.Security/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint.Search
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6531.5000
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/Microsoft.SharePoint.Search/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- msvcm80
>       Assembly Version: 8.0.50727.3053
>       Win32 Version: 8.00.50727.3053
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/WinSxS/x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_B80FA8CA/msvcm80.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Web
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3614 (GDR.050727-3600)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.DirectoryServices
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.DirectoryServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.DirectoryServices.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint.AdministrationOperation
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6500.5000
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SharePoint.AdministrationOperation/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.AdministrationOperation.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.SharePoint.Library
>       Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 12.0.6517.5000
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SharePoint.Library/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for
>   this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the
>   jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The
>   application must also be compiled with
>   debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any
>   unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the
>   computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: Just tried applying this security change http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926959.  No luck.  still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what else was installed on the server before installing SPS. However you might want to try to add your credential as a Site Collection Administrator to the site collection.

1. Open up the SharePoint Central Administration site.
2. Navigate to Application Management and click on Site collection Administrators.
3. From there you set your credential as the Site Collection Administrator for each Site Collection in each Web Application.
4. Run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard again. You'll probably get prompted as to whether you want to overwrite your default site or simply not create a default site. Afterwards you the wizard should finish properly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is related to some .net framework product not currently installed.. did you check the requirements for sharepoint services instalation?